# Euclidean TSP algorithms

Tags: tsp, dynamic-programming

Are there any known exact algorithms for Euclidean TSP that take advantage of the inherent structure of the problem?  Do any of these algorithms have better asymptotics than $O(2^n n^2)$ of a DP solution via Held-Karp?  I am also interested in simplicity of implementation (I've seen a 10-line implementation of Held-Karp in Python).

Is [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/11557/17264) still the current state of the art?

Comment: There is a subexponential $2^{O(\sqrt{n}\log n)}$-time algorithm for TSP in the plane (see page 90 of  http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/papers/phdthesis.pdf ). I'm not aware of any exact algorithms for higher dimensional Euclidean spaces, but I'm not terribly familiar with the literature on exact algorithms for TSP.

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question, but the Held-Karp algorithm can be sped up to $O(2^n n^{3/2})$, as described by Timothy Chan in his invited talk at WADS this year.